# How do I get the date values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from Google Analytics using Google Sheets Add-on.

I need to add in date range to pull the data from there.

I want to create a weekly report with week starting from Monday and ends at Sunday.

I am considering of creating a report to pull data like below.

Day | Visits | Unique Visitors | Goal Completions

After that, from the result table, I will then create a VLOOKUP and SUMIF formula to combine the date ranges. 
For example, if I want last week's data, I will look for data for date ranges from 2-July to 8-July.

The only problem with this approach is it might not be efficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

All I want is final output to look something like this:

Week (starting from Monday - ends at Sunday) | Visits | Unique Visitors | Goal Completions

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having problems to apply what you are considering to do? How are you measuring its performance?

Comment: Oh sorry for not clarifying clearly. What I want to know is if there is a possible way of creating an output table (as mentioned above) without having to SUMIF the individual dates data.

Answer (score 1):

Just add dimension ga:ISOWeek.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_isoweek